Pyspark drop duplicates when a column is null
I have a dataset like this :



id
name




1
A


2
null


2
B


3
C


3
null


4
null



In case of duplicate IDs, I want to keep the only value with a not null name
In this example, I want to get this table :



id
name




1
A


2
B


3
C


4
null



I tried to use the df.dropDuplicates() function, but I don't know how to specify to keep non-null value in "name" column

Please see the below link and see if it helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56852581/how-to-drop-duplicates-but-keep-the-rows-if-a-particular-other-column-is-not-nul

Here is an approach using window & distinct functions to eliminate duplicates.
df
.withColumn(
    "name", 
    expr("FIRST(name, TRUE) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id)")
)
.distinct
.show(10, False)

OR using groupBy
df
.groupBy("id")
.agg(first("name", true).as("name"))
.show(10, False)

OR using dropDuplicates
df
.orderBy("name", ascending=False)
.dropDuplicates(["id"])
.show(10, False)

+---+----+
|id |name|
+---+----+
|1  |A   |
|2  |B   |
|3  |C   |
|4  |NULL|
+---+----+

